# Is it feasible to start writing a question and SE could find which forum is best for the question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I had questions on several different topics like computer progrtamming, geogrphy, history, english, music etc. Could it work with some tool that can help me find the most suitable sub-site for a question based on content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Stack Exchange sites are not forums.*

If you have a viable question and you aren't sure where to ask it, the appropriate place to look for recommendations here, on Meta Stack Exchange. That's the purpose of the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag, and it's quite effective. Just be sure to include enough details about your question that it will be properly routable.

For instance, I've used this example before, don't say something like "where can I ask about the difficulties of flying across the Atlantic Ocean," because that could be suitable for [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com), [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com), or any number of other sites. Instead, list specifically what you're looking to find out. It's not a bad idea to draft up a preliminary form of your question and put it in a blockquote (put `>`s at the beginning of each line).

But remember, Stack Exchange *sites* are not forums. Forums tend to be very loose regulation-wise, and often involve discussion. If your question would lead to discussion, there's a good chance that no sites will be appropriate targets for it.